# How to further enhance this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $( document ).ready( function() {

    var dynamicChargableForm = 1;
    var dynamicDiscountForm = 1;

    var selectedId = 1;
    var newTextarea = null;

    var chargableHeader = document.getElementById( 'chargable-header' );
    var disountHeader = document.getElementById( 'discount-header' );

    var execute = null;

    $(document).on('keyup','.dynamic',function() {

       var typeName = this.id.split('-')[0];

       switch( typeName ) {

       case 'chargable':
             execute = dynamicRow( this, 'chargable', dynamicChargableForm , chargableHeader );
             execute ? dynamicChargableForm++ : execute = null;
             break;

       case 'discount' :
             execute = dynamicRow( this, 'discount', dynamicDiscountForm, disountHeader );
             execute ? dynamicDiscountForm++ : execute = null;
             break;
       }
    });
  });

  function dynamicRow( element, type , relatedTracker , relatedHeader )
  { 
     selectedId = element.id.split('-')[1];

     if ( selectedId == relatedTracker ) 
     {
        relatedTracker++;

        newTextarea = document.createElement( 'TEXTAREA' );
        newTextarea.setAttribute( 'name', type + '-' + relatedTracker );
        newTextarea.setAttribute( 'class' , 'form-control dynamic ' + type );
        newTextarea.setAttribute( 'id' , type + '-' + relatedTracker );

        relatedHeader.append( newTextarea );

        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

This is my first attempt to add a dynamically populate textarea when user input on the last added form . I would like to have advise and review on my code as i think that this code is not very efficient. I would like to have better understanding and standpoint from the expert.

Thank you

Comment: If your code works, this question fits better in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh , i see..
Thank you..
@kosmos

Comment: It's easy to abuse `?:`. I can't really spot at first sight whether `execute ? dynamicChargableForm++ : execute = null` does the right thing. Perhaps it's just me (I've learnt like 4 of 5 languages that implement the same operator and they don't all behave exactly the same way in all circumstances).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
         execute = dynamicRow( this, 'chargable', dynamicChargableForm , chargableHeader );
         execute ? dynamicChargableForm++ : execute = null;
```

By

```
         if(dynamicRow( this, 'chargable', dynamicChargableForm , chargableHeader )) {
           dynamicChargableForm++;
         }
```

I don't know why you need to add the dynamic name. Best way would be to set the name to `chargable[]`. The field will then be sent to the server as array.

Comment: You mean the input name?
To retrieve it in the controller

Comment: If you use `chargable[]` as input name, you can access all values in the controller as array. The exact way depends on your framework, but in PHP you can access `$_POST["chargable"][$i];`